# How to rewrite cookie to header in Istio?

Tags: istio

How to rewrite cookie to header in Istio?

Context: we have legacy Javascript webapp, which sends authorization data in cookie. Now we need this data in Auth adapter (in mixer) as well as in target service. Both Auth adapter and target service, expect this data in Authorization header.

Our first thought was to implement additional adapter in mixer, which rewrites cookie to Authorization header. Unfortunately it seems to be impossible:

- there is no way to get value of the cookie in instance configuration
  (no such attribute in vocabulary
  https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/mixer/attribute-vocabulary.html
  )
- I can not find template variety, which would allow to set the header in
  handler

Did I miss something? Or maybe we should implement something else - not adapter? What is recommended way to implement such requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the cookie sent as an HTTP header of the request? You have `request.headers` in the vocabulary. Your design with the mixer adapter looks correct - just extract the cookie from the `request.headers` map.

It seems you should use `TEMPLATE_VARIETY_ATTRIBUTE_GENERATOR` adapter, see this adapter as an example: https://github.com/istio/istio/tree/master/mixer/adapter/kubernetesenv.

Comment: OK. So I can handle Cookie header and parse it manually. But how to set Authorization header then, so it will be available for Auth adapter and also for the target service ?

Comment: I see, I do not know how to set an authorization header by Istio.

Comment: I can not find too much information about this variety: TEMPLATE_VARIETY_ATTRIBUTE_GENERATOR. What it exactly does?  How this attributes are interpreted by the envoy? Do you have maybe some docs about that?

Comment: @DamianPacierpnik I have no documentation about it either, will ask at the Istio Mixer slack.

Comment: @DamianPacierpnik Here is an issue about enabling setting Request Headers by Mixer https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/2706.

Comment: Ok, thank you for information. I will track this issue